# What resources can we recommend to Esperanto students?

Tags: learning, course

I'm aware of a number of good free resources online.  I thought it would be helpful to post this question so that we can provide students with a list of places to go.  For example,

Mi scias kelkajn bonajn senkostajn rimedojn surrete.  Mi pensis ke helpus se mi afiŝus ĉi tiun demandon por ke ni povu doni liston de TTT-ejoj al studentoj.  Ekzemple,

- [Reta Vortaro, ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/): Plurlingva vortaro de Esperanto.  Multilingual dictionary of Esperanto.
- [Plena Manlibro de Esperanta Gramatiko, PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/): Tre kompleta Esperanta gramatiko.  Nur Esperante.  A very complete Esperanto grammar.  In Esperanto only.
- [Being Colloquial in Esperanto](http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq003-Contents.html): Meznivela gvidlibro por anglaparolantaj studentoj de Esperanto.  An intermediate guidebook for English-speaking Esperanto students.

I'm looking for links, brief descriptions, and an indication of the language or languages that the resource is available in.

Mi serĉas ligilojn, mallongajn priskribojn, kaj indikon de la havebla(j) lingvo(j).

EDIT: I added Being Colloquial in Esperanto.

Comment: Kvankam de tre diversa kvalito **youtube** oferas distrajn filmetojn, por la kulturo diru.

Comment: FWIW, I have written 16 articles in Esperanto, which you can access here: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/dosierujo-artikoloj-en-esperanto.html

Answer (score 9):

For the younger students and beginners I would also recommend BaBaDum, which is a beautiful site where you can learn 1500 words by playing simple "games".

- [BaBaDum](https://babadum.com/)

The site itself is available in 20 different languages.

[image: BaBaDum - click on the matching object]

[image: BaBaDum - menus in 20 languages]

Answer (score 7):

## [lernu.net](http://lernu.net)

It contains forums in Esperanto, grammar of EO, and a library full of videos and songs.

Comment: I would like to also point out that Lernu is available in many languages

Answer (score 6):

Ankaŭ:

- [Vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net) - Reta vortaro - Internet
- [Duolingo - Esperanto](https://www.duolingo.com/course/eo/en/Learn-Esperanto-Online) - Esperanta Kurso - Esperanto Course
- [Esperantujo.directory](https://esperantujo.directory/) - La Esperantista Mondmapo - Esperantist Worldmap

Answer (score 6):

A corpus search is a very useful tool for a language learner. It lets you search a word or phrase in context. By using the two links below you can search for words and view them in their actual use in Esperanto literature, Zamenhof classics, monthly magazines, Vikipedio and more.

- [Tekstaro de Esperanto](http://tekstaro.com/) - menu in Esperanto only.
- [Corpuseye](http://corp.hum.sdu.dk/cqp.eo.html) - menu in English.

Answer (score 5):

En Telegram estas [granda listo](http://telegramo.org/) de grupoj kie oni povas ekzerci Esperanton parolante pri diversaj temoj. Ankaŭ estas multe da grupoj de Esperanto-plus-alia-lingvo kie komencantoj povas rapide demandi ion tra la alia lingvo.

Por vere lerni la lingvon oni kompreneble devas ekzerci paroli ĝin, kaj eble la plej bona maniero por fari tion estas iri al esperanta evento. Por trovi tion ekzistas [tre bona listo de multaj eventoj](http://eventoj.hu/kalendaro.htm).

Kiam ĝi finfine haveblos, ankaŭ [Amikumu](https://www.amikumu.com/eo/) estos la plej rapida maniero por trovi apudajn esperantistojn.

Por plibonigi sian skribitan esperanton, oni povas uzi [lang-8](http://lang-8.com) kiu estas retejo por iu ajn lingvo kie oni povas skribi ion en la celata lingvo kaj aliaj pli spertaj homoj korektos ĝin kaj donos konsilon.

Answer (score 2):

[Being Colloquial in Esperanto](http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq003-Contents.html) is a great resource for vocabulary, grammar usage, and explanations.  It is suggested to complete a beginner course (i.e. Duolingo) before delving into "Being Colloquial".  Advanced speakers often suggest that "Being Colloquial" be used for reference as opposed to reading it straight through like a textbook.

After completing Duolingo, I went straight to "Being Colloquial" and found it very interesting, entertaining, and educational.  I still go back and refresh my memory of it from time to time.  It's been a good resource for me.

Answer (score 0):

La ejo ‘Ekonomia Bulteno pri Usono’, rekte kaj libere atingebla, havas strikte paralelajn tekstojn angla – Esperanta. Jen la ligilo al ĝi:

https://ekonomiabultenopriusono.com/

La paralela formato de la traduko havas du celojn:

1. faciligi lingve-kontroli la tradukon;
   kaj
2. esti rimedo por lernantoj de la angla.

Answer (score 0):

for doubts about the pronunciation, I recommend https://forvo.com

It has native pronunciations in literally hundreds of languages